# Can't access module parameters in 1 file

Tags: joomla-2.5

When I do a var_dump in my default.php file, I get all the parameters en info from my module. However, I work with a seperate PHP file that takes the params that users enter in the admin panel, and puts them into a stylesheet. Thing is, this seperate file is not able to access the modules information. When I do a var_dump, all I get is this

```
object(stdClass)#120 (9) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(0)
  ["title"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["module"]=>
  string(16) "mod_improvedmenu"
  ["position"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["content"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["showtitle"]=>
  int(0)
  ["control"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["params"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["user"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

is there anything I should check?

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/jmodulehelpergetmodule-doesnt-return-parameters-in-joomla-3 .. as mentioned in my answer to your previous question, I would strongly recommend you **do not** use a separate PHP file. It's simply pointless in your situation. Joomla modules have a file structure already so make full use of it.

Comment: I fully agree with Lodder. You need to rethink your architecture. Do it in your regular module files and use `JFactory::getDocument()->addStyleDeclaration('your-rules-here')` (http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page)

Comment: if you'd see the size of the stylesheet you'd understand. it worked perfectly fine in the older version of the module. I just need to know how I can read the params in this file

Comment: I have decided to try and retrieve the params for the database. Mind you, this too is purely for practice. So, I was wondering if there was a specific way or function to read the params from the db and retrieve it as an object so that I may use it as $object->param1, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your are looking for a way access externally to modules information and parameters, you must go directly to the database and read #__modules table / params field. Params field is a JSON encoded string, it can be simply decoded calling *json_decode*.

Otherwise, implement a module following Joomla! CMS practices: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module

Comment: how would I then go about decoding the params as a usable object, so that I can for example use params->get('fontcolor') ?

Comment: They are enconded as JSON. You can use json_decode.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you need to hang onto these parameters, you could try SESSION variables or session storage. This implies that you actually have access to them before your separate PHP file executes.